# expression not working in f:facet? JSF

Tags: java, jsf

This expression is not working :-

```
  <f:facet name="header">
      Search Results for #{SearchResultsBean.searchPhrase}
  </f:facet>
```

But if i just remove that line from outside f:facet, it works. Why is this happening? Is this the intended behavior? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but this might be related to the fact that the `f:facet` can contain only **one** child. Try this instead:

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Search Results for #{SearchResultsBean.searchPhrase}" />
</f:facet>
```

or *maybe*

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:panelGroup>Search Results for #{SearchResultsBean.searchPhrase}</h:panelGroup>
</f:facet>
```

---

**Update**:

I just did a local test and actually, your initial approach works just here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    foo #{bean.text} bar
                </f:facet>
                #{item}
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

with

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class Bean {

    public List<String> getList() {
        return Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
    }

    public String getText() { 
        return "text";
    }

}
```

yields

> **foo text bar**
>   foo
>   bar

That was using Mojarra 2.0.2 on Tomcat 6.0.20. Which versions was you using? Was your approach similar?

Comment: Hi BalusC, fortunately/unfortunately, i am yet again using Primefaces :p. With h:dataTable it works fine, but with p:dataTable it doesn't. I am using Mojarra 2.0.2, Glassfish V3.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I was about to use Primefaces in an upcoming project. In future questions, it's good to mention name/version of JSF impl and libraries used. They might have their own inconsitenties.

Comment: Great BalusC, Primefaces is very good except it has many bugs and it is still evolving. I wanted a favor from you for all beginners like me using JSF. You have posted several articles about JSF. If you can just create a simple tutorial for building a simple component like Primefaces using JQUery or Yahoo Yui, it would be great. I inquired on Primefaces and they told me spinner, panel etc are very easy to design. If you can have the time to write such an article, i would be very grateful to you :). May be if you are busy now then after 1 month? If i am asking too much from you then sorry.

Comment: I've this in mind. I only wait for Eclipse Helios and Tomcat 7 to be released to have decent Java EE 6 / Servlet 3.0 / JSF 2.0 support in the tutorial. That might be around July/August.

Comment: Great! Wow, i am waiting for it eagerly :). Please let me know whenever you create it.

Comment: Yes, it will be great :) I also had an update of "using datatables" in mind with the -on paper- great `@ViewScope`, but unfortunately it has some serious bugs which make it less intuitive, as you know. I'd also like to wait for the JSF guys to fix them.